# $attributes not defined in block.json PHP template for ACF blocks

Tags: block-editor, advanced-custom-fields, json

I'm using ACF blocks to create custom dynamic blocks. Here is the code in the block.json file -

```
{
    "title": "Full Banner",
    "name": "lionsroar/full-banner",
    "category": "content",
    "icon": "slides",
    "viewScript": "full-banner-js",
    "style": "full-banner-css",
    "attributes": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        }
    },
    "variations": [
        {
            "name": "header-podcast",
            "title": "Header - Podcast",
            "description": "Header for the Podcasts page",            
            "attributes": {
                "title": "podcast"
            },
            "isDefault": true
        },
        {
            "name": "header-audio",
            "title": "Header - Audio",
            "description": "Header for the Audio page",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "audio"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "header-meditation",
            "title": "Header - Medidation",
            "description": "Header for the Medidation page",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "med"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "header-meditation-alt",
            "title": "Header - Meditation (Alt)",
            "description": "Alternate Header for the Podcasts page",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "med-alt"
            }
        }
    ],
    "acf": {
      "mode": "preview",
      "renderTemplate": "full-banner.php"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a block with variations and add different attribute for every variation.

The problem I'm having is I'm not able to access the attributes in the `full-banner.php` PHP file. While the [official docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#render) say that attributes are available in a `$attributes` variable. But it is showing undefined at my end. I even tried removing the variants. Even then I cannot access the attributes. Nothing worked.

As per [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-access-attributes-from-dynamic-blocks-in-php/), it should work but somehow it's not!

Any kind of help in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: The official docs are referring to the template set using `render` property. You're using ACF with the `acf.renderTemplate` property, so you'll need to check ACF's documentation for how to use that template.

Comment: Yea, it was the case. The attributes are part of the `$block` variable available in PHP file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out ACF blocks provide the attributes in the `$block` variable available in the PHP file mentioned in `renderTemplate` property of block.json. So, in my case it was available as `$block['title']`.